# Convert int to string, then fill the array with the converted elements

Tags: c

Iam trying to fill array with numbers that i converted from int to string. The output iam trying to get is {"0", "1", "2"...} but my array is filled with the last number that i converted {"19", "19", "19"..} idk why is that. Could you please help me guys ?

My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char *arr[20] = {};
    for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
        char str[20];
        itoa(i, str, 10);
        arr[i] = str;
    }
    
    for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Every element of  `char *arr[20]` points to `char str[20];` so they all point to the final string prepared. You could use `arr[i] = strdup(str);` if your system supports it.

Comment: Because you keep using the same `char` array over and over.  Try `char arr[20][20]`.

Comment: The code is actually *undefined behaviour*, because `char str[20];` is no longer a valid string by the time you come to report. Its scope ends with the first loop. So the pointer(s) you stored, just *happen* to word, unluckily.

Comment: arr[i] = strdup(str); - worked for me thank you so much !

Comment: Don't forget to `free` each element later! `strdup` allocates memory.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem**

`char str[20];` arranges that `str` is a pointer to the first element of a chunk of memory containing 20 `char`s. Since the `str` is a local variable to the `for` loop, **you cannot be sure what happens to that memory after the current iteration finishes.** It is undefined behaviour.

With that in mind, think about what `arr` will be at the the end of the first `for` loop.

It will be an array of 20 pointers to some bit of memory. But you can no longer be sure what the memory contains. It may be, as in your case, that they all point to the same bit of memory, which is filled with the last string that `itoa` put there. This might not happen in general though.

**Solution**

To fix this, you should probably use [`malloc`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdlib.h/malloc) to allocate new memory for each string you want to keep, within the first `for` loop. The memory is then heap allocated, and you can be sure that each call to `malloc` will give you a chunk of unused memory, such that you won't be overwriting previous strings. Try for example:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
        char *str = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * 20);
        itoa(i, str, 10);
        arr[i] = str;
    }
```

Note that it is also good practice to explicitly [`free`](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdlib.h/malloc#Memory_leaks) memory you have allocated with `malloc`.

Answer (score 1):

`char str[20];` creates a single location in memory where `str` is stored. It does not create  a *new* location each time the loop is run.

`arr[i] = str;` points each element of `arr` at that *one* location, which by the end of the loop contains just "19".

Instead of `arr[i] = str;` you need to do something like `strcpy(arr[i], str)` to copy the current contents of `str` to the appropriate element of `arr`.

Also, as Scott Hunter pointed out, you should declare `arr` using `char arr[20][20]` to have 20 unique char arrays to actually write the strings into.

I tested the following code (changed `itoa` to `sprintf`) and it worked for me:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char arr[20][20] = {};
    for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
        char str[20];
        sprintf(str, "%i", i);
        strcpy(arr[i], str);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your answers.

Comment: No, `strcpy(arr[i], str)` will probably cause a seg fault.

Comment: @WeatherVane I updated my answer with a complete code sample that worked for me, why would you expect `strcpy` to segfault?

Comment: Because the earlier version advised to `strcpy` to a random pointer of `char* arr[20]`, with no memory allocation.

Comment: That's what I thought. I wasn't sure you'd seen the update, but I wanted to be sure I wasn't missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Unrolling the loop, you get

```
arr[0] = str;
....
arr[1] = str;
....
arr[2] = str;
.... // etc
```

Which is basically:

```
arr[0] = arr[1] = arr[2] = arr[3] (...) = str;
```

So yeah, they all point to the same string. There is only one `str`.

There's also some undefined behaviour here. Firstly, all of your pointers `arr[0]` etc are being dereferenced here:

```
printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
```

when the thing they point to, `str`, has gone out of scope, there is no guarantee what might happen when you access it. Infact, the first "instance" of `str` goes out of scope at the end of the first iteration of the first loop. When you assign `arr[1]=str`, `arr[0]` is techincially invalid already. However, it likely that there is just one `str` that remains on the stack for the duration of the function, which would be consistent with the observed behaviour, but not guaranteed.

Try this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {

    char arr[20][20] = {}; // Allocate the space to store the results
    for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
    char str[20]; // Temp store
    itoa(i, str, 10);
    strcpy (arr[i], str); // Copy the string from the temp store
    // str goes out of scope NOW at the end of the loop, you cannot
    // any pointer that points to it either outside this loop or the next time
    // around the loop
}
// etc
```

Comment: You can avoid the copy by using `itoa(i,arr[i],10);`

Answer (score 0):

you need to allocate memory for each place in the `array, arr`. you can do this on the `stack` or on the `heap`. In this approach i have allocated the strings on the `heap`. So i called `malloc()` for allocating buffers of size `int` (no need to allocate more).

In my approach i have used `sprintf()` from `stdio.h` to convert the numbers to string format.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_INT_DIGITS_NUM 20 

int main() {

    char* arr[20]; /*this is an array of 20 char pointers*/
    for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
        arr[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * MAX_INT_DIGITS_NUM);
        sprintf(arr[i], "%d", i);
    }
    
    for(int i = 0;i < 20;i++){
        printf("%s\n", arr[i]);
        
        /*now you need to free all previous allocated buffers*/
        free(arr[i]);
    }
    
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

**what is wrong with your code?**

`arr` is only an array to `char pointers`! its not really holding `string buffers` that you can use for copy or scan to it! its only pointers that points to some address.

inside the `for` loop, you are declaring `str buffer` and you keep override it (itoa keeps copying to it) to the same place!! hence you exit the for loop in last iteration with only the last converted `i`!

now, just to aware you, after existing the `for loop` all the local variables marked by the os as `released`! so this can lead to memory corruption or override later in the program!

keep in mind that in my solution i always allocates `MAX_INT_DIGITS_NUM` bytes, no matter the `i` deget length. this is waste of memory! keep in mind that `itoa()` is not standard in `C` or `ansi c`!

Comment: `sizeof(int)` gives you the number of bytes required to store the int, not the number of bytes to store a string representing the decimal value of the int. For example if `sizeof(int)==4` you need to allocate enough bytes to store the string "-2147483648" whereas you are only allocating four bytes

Comment: @Rodney- you are right. my bad. i need to fix it to the size of MAX_INT (in worst case). in his case it worked since the largest number is 19 (which converted to 2 bytes for the 2 digits and one more for the null terminator. thanks i will fixit. my bad might !